# Alternate to SIFT to search through a folder of images?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift

I have a folder of images (around 10,000) that I need to search using a query image. Up until now, I have tried using SIFT to find matching images in my folder.

However, sometimes SIFT also matches two images that are relatively the same but not entirely. For instance, the two images below:

[image]
[image]

The above are matched, according to SIFT. The number of matches between the key-points is [sometimes] HIGHER between green and blue than between blue and blue! However, if instead I have the following as the train-image and one of the above images as the query image, the results are much better:

[image]

SIFT finds the correct box from the above image every time. However, that makes sense as SIFT is designed to find a matching image from a scene and not from a folder of individual images.

What other approach can I try for my particular purpose? The goal is to write a small piece of software that can identify the boxes.

I suppose one alternate would be to have one giant mosaic of the images and let SIFT hunt through it all. The issue, for me, here becomes that, even though the correct box was identified by SIFT, what does that box correspond to? For instance, in a folder each image had some meta-data that told me that this picture corresponds to this product.

Comment: Just to clarify : do you want the green one to be matched with the blue one (I guess no ?). How many images in your folder should be matched ? I'm not sure if it's what you want, but you can use SIFT as a descriptor for knnmatch and find the image that matches the best in your database

Comment: I want the blue one to be matched to the blue one. But as SIFT goes through the images, it obviously encounters the green one as well and so ends up matching blue to green.

Comment: So at the end you have 2 good matches (blue-green and blue-blue) ? you can just take the better one (blue-blue). If you know there's only one good match in your data set

Comment: @Saiph Yes, but what metric do I use to determine the better match? The number of matches between the key-points is HIGHER between green and blue than between blue and blue!

Comment: Here SIFT is your "distance". The idea is to compute a descriptor for each image in your data set, then the descriptor for the query image and find the nearest descriptor in the training set. You can use knnmatch for that (I think it uses the euclidian distance between the descriptors). Here you will use SIFT as a descriptor. I never did that with SIFT, but your approach looks good to me.

Comment: You can also try with [Opponent SIFT](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_extractors.html#opponentcolordescriptorextractor) which will take color into consideration.

Comment: @saad "The number of matches between the key-points is [sometimes] HIGHER between green and blue than between blue and blue!" -> I suggest you edit your question and add this somewhere. I didn't see this part or your message (no idea why) when I wrote my previous comment

Comment: Are you after "duplicates" search, same object search or "similar objects search"?

Comment: Then do Opponent SIFT, as @Miki suggested, because original SIFT is color-blind.